# Android to Windows tcp-communication delay

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I have developed an android client application and a windows c++ server application which communicate with tcp/ip in a local network.

The data exchange works well on my laptop (win 8, connected to the network with wifi).
On my second pc (win 7) the incoming messages are collected and forwarded in a bunch of about 20 messages to my application. As a consequence I only get about two times per second updates of the current sensor data (on the laptop ~30 times per second).

Both computers and the android phone are in the same local network. There are no other devices in the network and it is not connected to the internet. I already tried a wifi connection and a lan connection for the second pc without noticeable differences. 
I assume that any windows 7 setting is responsible for this behavior.

Comment: Could also be your network card/driver, a slower PC due to CPU/memory/load from other apps etc..  Does it matter anyway?  You're getting updates that may be lagged by half a second instead of 3 hundredths - is the user going to care?

Comment: The smartphone is used as a input device to navigate through a 3D-environment on the computer (with the data of android gravity-sensor). With about 30 updates/second this feels good, with 2 updates/second you are always waiting for the response after changing the smartphone orientation.
The second PC has better hardware then the laptop and the second pc has the issue with an wifi-stick, while the laptop has no issue while beeing connected with the same stick. No other programs are running.

Comment: Is nagling enabled? Disable it.

Comment: wow disabling nagling helped! Thank you, perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using nagling which batches small sends for 200ms. Disable it, but make sure to send big chunks at a time. Each send call immediately goes on the network now.